# Old Nulls and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm moving a sloppy old Access DB to a crisp new SQL Server database and using EF Code First to design and manage the DB.

I started it out locking down all the stuff that I did not want to be nulls, but then I got to the sloppy old data and found that there were nulls in the old data in many places. I can't recreate the old data from history, so I guess I need to allow nulls in the new DB.

...but I definitely want to prevent any more sloppy data entering the db. If I put a [Required] attribute it will block new bad data but it will also create the db column as NOT NULL and therefore prevent the migration of the old data.

So how do I lock down the DB to prevent new nulls coming in? Of course I can secure the UI to prevent it, but I'm kind of paranoid and would love to lock the DB down to not allow new rows having nulls. One way to do this is to go behind EF and write a trigger to throw an exception if the Inserted row contains nulls in the columns I want to protect. That will work but I was wondering if there is some way to do it directly in EF and have less code to maintain.

Comment: I don't know about EF, i.m an NHibernate guy. But in situations like this, it's better to use import/export for data migrations. I can suggest you dump olda data as json and when importing to check that data for nulls before inserting to the database.

Comment: You can leave your Entity models or fluent code as not required, but then annotate or otherwise validate your viewmodels to be [Required] so if anyone edits legacy data it will now be required. You could also look at running a database script to replace the nulls with some default value.

Comment: Many `null` values might also be a telltale of bad database design. You may consider further normalization, converting `null`s into non-existing child records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different solution to the one you have thought: when importing the data, convert old nulls to new special values. In this way, you'll get all the benefits of not having nulls on your DB. This is not what you're looking for, but I've done when importing data to a new applications, ant I thought you could use this solution too. When I import missing or invalid data I convert it to special value that I usually call "historic".

To answer your concrete question, if you want to do custom validation in EF, there are several solutions:

- implement [IValidatableObject interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959#IValidatableObject)
- override [DbContext.ValidateEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959#ValidateEntity)
- using custom validation attributes, as [shown in this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/741012/Validation-attributes-in-Code-First)

One thing that you must have into account if you use one of theses solutions is that, if a user tries to update some data that had nulls in the database, and he wants to keep the nulls, the validation must be aware of that, or it will show the error of the old null field being null again. The first solution proposed in this answer doesn't have this problem.